# ACAccountStore not retrieving Facebook Account for Custom SLRequest

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

Currently, I'm building an app that utilizes the new iOS 6 Social framework to gather a Facebook account stored in iOS, and create a custom SLRequest to post a status update and photo to the user's timeline. I have configured an app in the Facebook Dev Center, and have received my App ID, however, when I try to request the Facebook account through ACAccountStore, I always get the following localized error message:

```
2012-10-14 17:34:46.429 Status Update[12042:4c0b] The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 8.)
```

Here's the code that I'm currently using to process the request to get the account from the Account Store:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
@"ACFacebookAppIdKey" : @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
@"ACFacebookPermissionsKey" : @[@"publish_stream"],
@"ACFacebookPermissionGroupKey" : @[@"write", @"email"]};

self.facebookStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
self.facebookAccountType = [self.facebookStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
self.facebookAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:self.facebookAccountType];
[self.facebookStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.facebookAccountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
{
    if (granted)
    {
        NSArray *accounts = [self.facebookStore accountsWithAccountType:self.facebookAccountType];
        self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
        NSLog(@"Facebook Account Enabled: %@", _facebookAccount);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error.localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Don't know if you resolved your problem but the same thing is happening to me. Something I noticed is that the same result is given even if the appID isn't specified like this NSDictionary *options = @{
    @"ACFacebookAppIDKey": @"",

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

And note:

When requesting access to Facebook accounts, the only key required in your options dictionary is ACFacebookAppIdKey. ACFacebookPermissionGroupKey and ACFacebookAppVersionKey are now obsolete.

If you request a write permission under ACFacebookPermissionsKey, such as publish_stream, you must provide a value for ACFacebookAudienceKey, which can be one of ACFacebookAudienceEveryone, ACFacebookAudienceFriends, or ACFacebookAudienceOnlyMe.

```
NSDictionary *options = @{
ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"XXXXXXXX",
ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream"],
ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
};
```